# What section does the Entity relationship diagram (ERD) go for a thesis?

Tags: entity-relationship

I am writing a thesis on an android application. 
I am unsure if the Entity relationship diagram (ERD) goes under: 
Chapter 4: System requirements and specifications 
or 
Chapter 5: System Design

Comment: Chapter 5: System Design

ERD diagrams are what you designed for the entities. It has no relationship with system requirements and specifications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has more to do with academic best practices than programming.

Comment: Imagine you're the developer (and just the developer) - is the ERD a business *requirement* or something you, as the developer would develop?

Answer (score 1):

ER Diagram should go under System Design. It is a system design which explains the business requirements.

Comment: but business requirements should be in System requirements and specifications

Comment: @Rashid: Yeah those requirements are represented as a design in ER i believe. So I think ER should go under system design

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 5: System Design

ERD diagrams are what you designed for the entities. It has no relationship with system requirements and specifications.